# Grails TypeChecked / CompileStatic / GrailsCompileStatic

Tags: generics, grails, project, type-safety, duck-typing

Is there a way to add the functionality for @TypeChecked, @GrailsCompileStatic, @CompileStatic  to an entire grails project?

To explain code I am now working on is in grails, simple things that I would expect to be compilation failures simply pass, and sometimes work, other times it just wait for run time to throw failures.  Other things like using Generics throw compilation errors.

@TypeChecked fixes the generic issues, @GrailsCompileStatic and @CompileStatic highlight a lot of other issues misnamed variables, things that don't exist, mismatched types, and other things that may or may not "automagically work".

Comment: If you do this, you're going to lose a lot of capabilities that groovy provides.  I'm not sure if it's possible or not, but I can't imagine it's going to be a great experience if you do manage it.  It may be better for the long term to address whatever is causing your errors.

Comment: I am not sure what "features" groovy provides other than moving errors from compile time to run time.

Comment: You may want to read up on groovy some then.  The official documentation is very good, but I have found a lot of real-world examples that aren't always obvious at https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/ also.  Obviously not every language is a good fit for every project, but it sounds like you're stuck with groovy (and grails) at least for now, so might as well learn how to use it to its fullest!  The groovy/grails community here isn't super active but is usually very helpful if you run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to add the functionality for @TypeChecked,
>   @GrailsCompileStatic, @CompileStatic to an entire grails project?

No.  There are aspects of Grails apps that require dynamic dispatch.  You cannot statically type check and statically compile everything in a Grails app.

Answer (score 1):

While I do agree with what others say you will lose out in certain areas.

However, you could try the Enterprise Groovy Gradle plugin:
https://virtualdogbert.github.io/enterprise-groovy-plugin/

This will give you static compilation by default, but will also slow you to white-list the places that need dynamic compilation. There is a Grails config that worked at one point for a simple app. Your mileage may vary. This project won't give you IDE support though like @CompileStatic will.

Also, full disclosure this is one of my side projects.